# n divides $m+1, m^m+1, m^{m^m}+1,...$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that for each positive integer n, there is a positive integer m such that each term of the infinite sequence $m+1, m^m+1, m^{m^m}+1,...$ is divisible by n.

The only thing I could work out was that the sequence is all even if $m$ is odd, so $n=2$ works. I would be pleased if you can help!

Comment: $m=2n-1$ works for all $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you clarify how $({2n-1})^{2n-1}+1$ would be divisible by $n$?

Comment: What the comment of @ThomasAndrews is signifying is that if [1] $n ~| ~(m+1)$ and [2] $m$ is odd, then it works.  this is because for any odd positive integer $k$, you have that $(m+1)$ divides $\left(m^k\right) + 1.$

Comment: In general, if $k$ is odd, $a+1\mid a^k+1.$

Comment: @user2661923 I see now. Thanks. Now I can finish the proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your help, now I will conclude the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer after **reading the comments**:

Let $m=2n-1$ (odd). Then the first term of the sequence works for every $n$: $n \mid m+1=2n$.

To prove that it works for all the sequences' terms, we will use the following:

> $a+1 \mid a^k+1$ for an odd $k$

and so $n \mid a^k+1$. Checking if $k$ is odd:

In the second term, $k=m$ and $m$ is odd. In the n-th term, $k=m\uparrow \uparrow (n-1)$, and since $odd^{{odd}^{\dots}} \equiv odd $ we can choose a $m$ by a $n$ and we are done.